How to send invite and receive invite using sip js?
I am new in sip.js. I want to create simple html page using sip.js with functionality of

Call from brother
Receive call from browser
End call from browser.
Cancel call from browser.
Mute and unmute call from browser.

Anyone please suggest any sample code or any reference for it.
